# Can I break an SQL statement with JOINs into smaller queries or optimize query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have query that's breaking an area of my website. The site spins forever when attempting to load the following SQL statement! I'm fairly new to sql statements and this particular statement was created by another developer. Is there a way to optimize the following statement? Or break it up into smaller statements so that it will run more quickly? I'm at a loss! I appreciate any help.

```
SELECT
    `wp_quiz_users`.`Id`,
    `wp_quiz_users`.`SessionId`,
    `wp_quiz_users`.`Score`,
    `wp_quiz_users`.`Date`,
    `wp_quiz_users`.`Referrer`,
    `wp_quiz_users`.`ContactData`,
    (SELECT
        SUM(`wp_quiz_users_answers`.`AnswerValue`) 
    FROM
        `wp_quiz_users_answers` 
    JOIN
        `wp_quiz_questions` 
            ON `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`QuestionId` = `wp_quiz_questions`.`id` 
    WHERE
        `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`UserId` = `wp_quiz_users`.`Id` 
        AND `wp_quiz_questions`.`Category` = 1) AS `SectionOne`,
    (SELECT
        SUM(`wp_quiz_users_answers`.`AnswerValue`) 
    FROM
        `wp_quiz_users_answers` 
    JOIN
        `wp_quiz_questions` 
            ON `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`QuestionId` = `wp_quiz_questions`.`id` 
    WHERE
        `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`UserId` = `wp_quiz_users`.`Id` 
        AND `wp_quiz_questions`.`Category` = 2) AS `SectionTwo`,
    (SELECT
        SUM(`wp_quiz_users_answers`.`AnswerValue`) 
    FROM
        `wp_quiz_users_answers` 
    JOIN
        `wp_quiz_questions` 
            ON `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`QuestionId` = `wp_quiz_questions`.`id` 
    WHERE
        `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`UserId` = `wp_quiz_users`.`Id` 
        AND `wp_quiz_questions`.`Category` = 3) AS `SectionThree`,
    (SELECT
        SUM(`wp_quiz_users_answers`.`AnswerValue`) 
    FROM
        `wp_quiz_users_answers` 
    JOIN
        `wp_quiz_questions` 
            ON `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`QuestionId` = `wp_quiz_questions`.`id` 
    WHERE
        `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`UserId` = `wp_quiz_users`.`Id` 
        AND `wp_quiz_questions`.`Category` = 4) AS `SectionFour`,
    (SELECT
        SUM(`wp_quiz_users_answers`.`AnswerValue`) 
    FROM
        `wp_quiz_users_answers` 
    JOIN
        `wp_quiz_questions` 
            ON `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`QuestionId` = `wp_quiz_questions`.`id` 
    WHERE
        `wp_quiz_users_answers`.`UserId` = `wp_quiz_users`.`Id` 
        AND `wp_quiz_questions`.`Category` = 5) AS `SectionFive` 
FROM
    `wp_quiz_users`
```

Comment: That query is insane looking.  For your future reference, queries are not supposed to look like that.  Be suspicious of any query that mentions the same tables over and over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is similar to Gordon's except that it performs the aggregation for the sums inside a separate subquery.  This frees the outer query from needing to aggregate, and hence there should be no problem at all selecting any columns we want from the `wp_quiz_users` table.

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t1.SessionId,
    t1.Score,
    t1.Date,
    t1.Referrer,
    t1.ContactData,
    COALESCE(t2.SectionOne, 0)   AS SectionOne,
    COALESCE(t2.SectionTwo, 0)   AS SectionTwo,
    COALESCE(t2.SectionThree, 0) AS SectionThree,
    COALESCE(t2.SectionFour, 0)  AS SectionFour,
    COALESCE(t2.SectionFive 0)   AS SectionFive
FROM wp_quiz_users t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        t1.UserId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Category = 1 THEN t1.AnswerValue ELSE 0 END) AS SectionOne,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Category = 2 THEN t1.AnswerValue ELSE 0 END) AS SectionTwo,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Category = 3 THEN t1.AnswerValue ELSE 0 END) AS SectionThree,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Category = 4 THEN t1.AnswerValue ELSE 0 END) AS SectionFour,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Category = 5 THEN t1.AnswerValue ELSE 0 END) AS SectionFive
    FROM wp_quiz_users_answers t1
    INNER JOIN wp_quiz_questions t2
        ON t1.QuestionId = t2.id 
    GROUP BY t1.UserId
) t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.UserId;
```

Comment: . . There is no problem choosing all columns from the users table, either in MySQL or ANSI SQL (under the reasonable assumption that the `id` column is unique).  ANSI SQL permits databases to select all columns from a row, when a unique key is used for aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I know this...I was just being paranoid should the `Id` column for some reason not be a primary key column.  Or perhaps a refactor at a later date might change this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you so much!! You're a miracle maker. I've been hacking at this statement for days.

Comment: @Christy You should also give Gordon's answer a look, assuming it runs without error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT qu.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 1 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) as SectionOne, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 2 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) as SectionTwo, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 3 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) as SectionThree, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 4 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) as SectionFour, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 5 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) as SectionFive
FROM wp_quiz_users qu LEFT JOIN
     wp_quiz_users_answers qa
     ON qa.UserId = q.id  LEFT JOIN
     wp_quiz_questions qq
     ON qa.QuestionId = qq.id 
GROUP BY qu.UserId;
```

Comment: I countered the downvote.  I also don't know why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to that by Gordon Linoff but I wanted to add a note on syntax you may need at some point. Standard behaviour for SQL is that all columns that do not involve an aggregation function [e.g. `sum()`] should be listed in the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT
      wp_quiz_users.Id
    , wp_quiz_users.SessionId
    , wp_quiz_users.Score
    , wp_quiz_users.Date
    , wp_quiz_users.Referrer
    , wp_quiz_users.ContactData
    , SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 1 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) AS sectionone
    , SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 2 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) AS sectiontwo
    , SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 3 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) AS sectionthree
    , SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 4 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) AS sectionfour
    , SUM(CASE WHEN qq.Category = 5 THEN qa.AnswerValue END) AS sectionfive
FROM wp_quiz_users qu
LEFT JOIN wp_quiz_users_answers qa ON qa.UserId = q.id
LEFT JOIN wp_quiz_questions qq ON qa.QuestionId = qq.id
GROUP BY
      wp_quiz_users.Id
    , wp_quiz_users.SessionId
    , wp_quiz_users.Score
    , wp_quiz_users.Date
    , wp_quiz_users.Referrer
    , wp_quiz_users.ContactData
;
```

i.e. It is good practice to list out all the columns you need in the select clause, and also all the "non-aggregating" columns also listed in the group by clause.

IF you see a query using like this:

```
select * from sometable group by name
```

Then that query relies an a non-standard MySQL extension that can be turned on or off. If that extension is turned off queries reliant on the extension will begin to fail. So, a prudent coder can avoid that potential problem by simply listing all the non-aggregating columns in the group by clause. see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

---

Regarding the original query it contains many "correlated subqueries" inside the select clause, and as you have discovered that are awful for performance. Be on the lookout for these

```
 select name
   , (select sum(value) from tablex 
      where tablex.id = table1.id   -- the "correlation" of tablex to table1 is here
     )
 from table1
```

Occasionally however they can be a decent option, so while thay are to be avoided most of the time we cannot just say never use them at all.

Comment: This is not entirely correct.  If aggregating by a key column, then any column which is functionally dependent on that key may be selected without adding it to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Note the term "should" not "must". I am aware of the that you can (if sufficiently aware) rely on "functional dependence". However this isn't always obvious or easy to understand to newcomers. What I am trying to convey is the reliance on non-standard syntax can/will lead to issues.

Comment: I agree, which is why I posted the answer which I did +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with

```
    FROM (
        SELECT  ua.`UserId`,
                q.Category,
                SUM(ua.`AnswerValue`)
            FROM  `wp_quiz_users_answers` AS ua
            JOIN  `wp_quiz_questions` AS q
              ON ua.`QuestionId` = q.`id`
            GROUP BY ua.`UserId`, q.Category
         ) AS x
    JOIN wp_quiz_users AS u
      ON u.Id = x.UserId
```

and build up around it.

(But since I see other answers, I'll be lazy and not finish this thought.)

Hmmm... I wonder if my approach -- or the other approaches -- will inflate the `SUMs` due to waiting too late to do `GROUP BY`??